# powershell regex in switch not returning a value

Tags: regex, powershell

For some reason, regex doesn't return a value. So, when I do a write-host $d[3], it doesn't return anything. But when I put the same regex in its own switch (without the domain, smtp, 5digit), it works fine. Why is that?

```
Function _getCountrySettings #Add additional countries to the switch statement
{
    param($CountryID)
    switch ($CountryID)
        {
           #"XX" {$d = ('user AD domain','*@ smtp domain','number of digits in the extension')}
            "ES" {$d = ('eurs.abc.net','*@es.abc.com','5digit','^(\+[3][4])?([1-9]\d\d{7})$')}          #Spain
            "CZ" {$d = ('eure.abc.net','*@cz.abc.com','5digit','^(\+[4][2][0])?([1-9]\d\d{7})$')}           #Czech Republic
            "UK" {$d = ('uk.eurw.abc.net','*@uk.abc.com','5digit')}                                     #UK
            "IE" {$d = ('eurw.abc.net','*@ie.abc.com','5digit')}                                            #Ireland        
    Default {write-host "[ERROR] Country Code not found"; exit}
        }
    return $d
}
```

Comment: If your switch test is a regex, you have to add the -Regex parameter to the Switch statement. The default is use a literal string (not substring) match.

Answer (score 1):

I just found

```
"ES" {$d = ('eurs.abc.net','*@es.abc.com','5digit')
```

at the bottom of the switch. That's why ES wasn't returning the regex.